# Moving Data from One Query to Another Table

Tags: mysql

I am having a hard time in access trying to create the right code. I need help moving values from one query(qryRates) to another table(Table1).

qryrates has the following data:

> **EUR**   **GBP**
>       1.3       1.6

Table1 has the following data:

> **Currency**      **Rate**
>       EUR
>       GBP

All i need to do is get the rates from "qryrates"  and populate Table1 with the corresponding rates. So that in Table1 under the Rate column I would have 1.3 for EUR and 1.6 for GBP. 
Thank you so much

Comment: Can you describe the schema for both tables? There's no column names here.

Comment: qryrates Columns are EUR and GBP

Comment: Table1 columns are Currency and Rate

Comment: So there's just one row in the original table?

Comment: Yes, just one row in qryrates and two rows in Table1

Comment: I just need to populate the two empty rows under the Rate column in Table1, with the values from qryrates

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT INTO SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

For your case in particular:

```
INSERT 
INTO Table1(Rate) 
SELECT EUR FROM qryrates 
WHERE (EUR > 100);
```

Read the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Comment: INSERT INTO Table1 ( Rate )
SELECT [qryrates].EUR
FROM qryrates
WHERE ((([qryrates].EUR)>100));

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO table1 (Currency, Rate)
SELECT 'EUR', (SELECT EUR FROM qryrates);
INSERT INTO table1 (Currency, Rate)
SELECT 'GBP', (SELECT GBP FROM qryrates);

Comment: I copied and paste it but didnt work " Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement